# Unable to capture program exit

Tags: shell, io-redirection, exit

I started a program written using Node.js and started it using launch pipe into logfile and send it to background.

Half way running the program exited w/o any error both on the console nor the log, I even checked the /var/log/message and no way I could figure out what's wrong with the program.

Are there any better way to able to capture the error/messages that causes the exit?

The current execution bash script is following:

```
./run_all_with_logs >> logs/my.log &
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's enhance P.T.:s answer just a little.

The basic form sends all normal output to the log file.

```
./run_all_with_logs >> logs/my.log &
```

If we redirect the errors we can log both the errors and the normal printouts.

```
./run_all_with_logs 2>&1 >> logs/my.log &
```

If we then executes the command in a subshell we can print the exit code as well.

```
(./run_all_with_logs ; echo "Final Exit Code: $?" ) 2>&1  >> logs/my.log &
```

Comment: Yeah, including stderr is a very important addition.

Answer (score 4):

The exit code should tell you if the process was killed by an external signal or exited with a (hopefully useful) internal exit code on its own.

You can expand your command-line a bit to include the exit code (see other questions for decoding this exit code):

```
(./run_all_with_logs ; echo "Final Exit Code: $?" ) >> logs/my.log &
```

You could make this a bit fancier (decoding exit status, etc).

Comment: Add the magical 2>&1 so you log the errors as well, and your answer will be even better.

Comment: @Johan: better keep the changes minimal with respect to the OP's command line or you would confuse everyone.